# creation of threads in TBB thread pool when the number of threads have exceeded max number of processes

Tags: multithreading, process, tbb

I ran into a problem while running a multi threaded code which gave the following error:
"Resource temporarily unavailable"
what does TBB do when the number of threads exceed the number of processes on the machine?
There was no error message from the TBB parallel invocations